# Simple velocity will not function?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, velocity

I have two lines of code, that in every way I can tell, are exactly the same. Yet one works the way it should, while the other one does nothing. I know it sounds inane but this is driving me nuts and any advice would be a life-saver:

First the one that works:

```
public Rigidbody2D pBlock;

if (playerReference.GetComponent<Player>()){
Debug.Log ("got to debug");
            pBlock.velocity = new Vector2(10, 0);
        }
```

Now the one that doesn't:

```
       public Rigidbody2D playerRigid;

  public void Update()
    {
        if (conveyorBeltLeft.conveyorPlayerLeft) {
         Debug.Log ("got to debug");
            playerRigid.velocity = new Vector2(-100, 500000);
        }
```

The first one, the object moves, the second one, it doesn't. In both of them the debug goes off. Please someone explain this to me is everything I've learned about Unity so far entirely wrong?

Comment: I can't think about any possible reason why this sould not work. Is the second line called from another thread, or the same main thread?

Comment: The one block of code is in one script on one object, the other is another script on another object

Comment: This is understandable from your question. But is one of them called from a differend thread?

Comment: sorry I don't understand. I am using addforce now with better results:
 if (conveyorBeltLeft.conveyorPlayerLeft) {
   Debug.Log ("got to playerConveyor If");
      //playerRigid.velocity = new Vector2(-100, 500000);
   playerRigid.AddForce(forceRate*Vector2.left*Time.deltaTime) ;
  }

Comment: All scripts in Unity are single-threaded.

Answer (score 0):

Some thoughts:

- Check that `playerRigid.isKinematic` is `false`
- Check that `playerRigid` is not asleep (`IsSleeping()` should return false)
- Check that there are no constraints on `playerRigid` (i.e. `playerRigid.constraints` is set to `None`)